# Ethernet shield or Wifi sheild - Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, ethernet

To control some LEDs through internet using Arduino UNO, which type of connection  is better ? Ethernet or Wifi? (Later, I may connect some relays instead of LEDs, and control (turn on and off) some devices using this setup). 
The only difference I know is the wired and wireless connectivity. 
Is there any other difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are beginner with Arduino its better to start with [Ethernet Shield](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoEthernetShield). Its much more easy to connect with Arduino.

WiFi Module - [ESP8266](http://www.esp8266.com/) required some more knowledge, that you will learn in future.

The bought products are cheap, so you can start with Ethernet and after that to switch to ESP.